# How do I solve GATE building file make error

Tags: cmake, centos

I am installing gate on centOS 7. Almost finish all installation besides a little error when I try to build installation file in build directory before final installation, `make install`. Here is the command line response:

```
100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Gate.dir/source/physics/src/GateXrayBoundaryPB.cc.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Gate.dir/source/physics/src/GateeMultipleScatteringPB.cc.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Gate.dir/source/physics/src/GatehMultipleScatteringPB.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Gate
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libtbb.so.2, needed by /home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libImt.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libvdt.so, needed by /home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libROOTVecOps.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libRDAVIX.so.6.18, needed by /home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libROOTDataFrame.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libROOTDataFrame.so: undefined reference to `Davix::DavPosix::pread(Davix_fd*, void*, unsigned long, long, Davix::DavixError**)'
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libImt.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_scheduler_init::initialize(int)'
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libImt.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'

/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libImt.so: undefined reference to `tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id)'
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libImt.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::is_group_execution_cancelled() const'
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libImt.so: undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libImt.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::reset()'
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libImt.so: undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_terminate()'
...
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libROOTDataFrame.so: undefined reference to `Davix::DavPosix::stat(Davix::RequestParams const*, std::string const&, stat*, Davix::DavixError**)'
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libROOTDataFrame.so: undefined reference to `Davix::DavixError::getErrMsg() const'
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libImt.so: undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_execute(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&) const'
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libROOTDataFrame.so: undefined reference to `Davix::Context::~Context()'
/home/xincao/GATE/root_v6.18/lib/libImt.so: undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Gate] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Gate.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone can help? Any reply will be highly appreciated!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is because the geant4.sh script in the Geant4 bin has not been run.  This sets up the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable which then allows these libraries to be found.  (Note that you will need the data from CERN in order to successfully run geant4.sh)

Comment: Thany you anyway, that problem have been solved for a long time.